# How can I separate runs of my TensorFlow code in TensorBoard?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorboard

My [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html) plots treat successive runs of my [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org) code as if they are all part of the same run. For example if I first run my code (below) with `FLAGS.epochs == 10` and then rerun it with `FLAGS.epochs == 40` I get

[image]

which "loops back" at the end of the first run to begin the second.

Is there a way to treat multiple runs of my code as distinct logs, that, for example, could be compared or individually viewed?

---

```
from __future__ import (absolute_import, print_function, division, unicode_literals)

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

# Basic model parameters as external flags.
flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
flags.DEFINE_float('epochs', 40, 'Epochs to run')
flags.DEFINE_integer('mb_size', 40, 'Mini-batch size. Must divide evenly into the dataset sizes.')
lags.DEFINE_float('learning_rate', 0.15, 'Initial learning rate.')
flags.DEFINE_float('regularization_weight', 0.1 / 1000, 'Regularization lambda.')
flags.DEFINE_string('data_dir', './data', 'Directory to hold training and test data.')
flags.DEFINE_string('train_dir', './_tmp/train', 'Directory to log training (and the network def).')
flags.DEFINE_string('test_dir', './_tmp/test', 'Directory to log testing.')

def variable_summaries(var, name):
    with tf.name_scope("summaries"):
        mean = tf.reduce_mean(var)
        tf.scalar_summary('mean/' + name, mean)
        with tf.name_scope('stddev'):
            stddev = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(var - mean)))
            tf.scalar_summary('sttdev/' + name, stddev)
    tf.scalar_summary('max/' + name, tf.reduce_max(var))
    tf.scalar_summary('min/' + name, tf.reduce_min(var))
    tf.histogram_summary(name, var)

def nn_layer(input_tensor, input_dim, output_dim, neuron_fn, layer_name):
    with tf.name_scope(layer_name):
        # This Variable will hold the state of the weights for the layer
        with tf.name_scope("weights"):
            weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([input_dim, output_dim], stddev=0.1))
            variable_summaries(weights, layer_name + '/weights')
        with tf.name_scope("biases"):
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[output_dim]))
            variable_summaries(biases, layer_name + '/biases')
        with tf.name_scope('activations'):
            with tf.name_scope('weighted_inputs'):
                weighted_inputs = tf.matmul(input_tensor, weights) + biases
                tf.histogram_summary(layer_name + '/weighted_inputs', weighted_inputs)
            output = neuron_fn(weighted_inputs)
            tf.histogram_summary(layer_name + '/output', output)
    return output, weights 

# Collect data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)

# Inputs and outputs
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

# Network structure
o1, W1 = nn_layer(x, 784, 30, tf.nn.sigmoid, 'hidden_layer')
y, W2 = nn_layer(o1, 30, 10, tf.nn.softmax, 'output_layer')

with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
    with tf.name_scope('loss'):
        cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
        loss = cost + FLAGS.regularization_weight * (tf.nn.l2_loss(W1) + tf.nn.l2_loss(W2))
    with tf.name_scope('correct_prediction'):
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    tf.scalar_summary('accuracy', accuracy)
    tf.scalar_summary('loss', loss)

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate).minimize(loss)

# Logging
train_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(FLAGS.train_dir, tf.get_default_graph())
test_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(FLAGS.test_dir)
merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    for ep in range(FLAGS.epochs):
        for mb in range(int(len(mnist.train.images)/FLAGS.mb_size)):
            batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(FLAGS.mb_size)
            sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

        summary = sess.run(merged, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels})
        test_writer.add_summary(summary, ep+1)
```

Comment: Put them in different subdirectories, then they will show up as separate runs

Comment: @etarion: Yes, except that obvious way. So: same directory means same run by definition, regardless of whether the code was actually run at different times or whether different files were (automatically) generated? Or, put another way (this is really the question): there's no way to distinguish separate log files within a directory?

Comment: when you save/resume a run, you don't want to distinguish separate log files ... there could be an option, but if there is, I don't know of one.

Comment: @etarion: I *do* want to, and there should indeed be a way to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from fs.osfs import OSFS
folder = OSFS(FLAGS.test_dir)
test_n = len(list(n for n in folder.listdir() if n.startswith('test')))
this_test = FLAGS.test_dir+"/test" + str(test_n+1)
test_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(this_test)
```

You could use something like this to have your runs enumerated.

Answer (score 13):

You can put your runs into separate subdirectories, like:

```
./logdir/2016111301/
./logdir/2016111302/
./logdir/2016111401/
```

than you call your tensorboard function on the root dir:

```
tensorboard --logdir=logdir
```

Than you will have the separate logfiles like:

[image]

Comment: That's not the question though. The question is *how* to do that (as has been answered).

Comment: That's why I wrote "put your runs into separate subdirectories". Or did I missunderstood the question? And why didn't you accepted any answer yet, if you got your answer to your question already?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the (low-level) "time" module to get a string for whenever the run starts, and name the directory accordingly..

Here's an example using keras with the TensorFlow backend

```
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import time

now = time.strftime("%c")
model.fit(X, Y, batch_size = 2, nb_epoch = 100, shuffle = True,
        verbose = 1, validation_split = 0.1, 
        callbacks =[TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs/'+now, histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True)])
```

This will give you a set of directories such as

```
% ls logs
Fri Sep  2 23:58:39 2016/ Sat Sep  3 00:05:41 2016/
```

...yes, the names have spaces in them, but Tensorboard doesn't mind.  You'll see a list of runs, color-coded and date-time stamped based on when they started.